# Is there any CSS code to show a text below the cursor if we hover and place it over for some time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Many websites have a feature that when some box or image or any element is hovered and place on it for some time just below the cursor a text is shown (describes or tell that what that item is) . how can we make one like that ?

As I am new to web development I do not know whether its related to CSS or not . If yes I want a small explanation and code along demo image (if possible for the output) . Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about `tooltip`
You can do it with the `title` attribute or build your custom `tooltip`.
You can hover over this test button:

```html
<button title='This is a test button'>Test button</button>
```